# Questions about Activity and SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a question in regards with my timed window card quiz app for math that I am trying to develop. So here it goes:

1. Is it possible to use 1 activity for my 10 or more questions?
2. Can I use SQLite as a database for variables like integer, float or double?

Any answers pertaining to my questions are highly appreciated. Happy weekends, folks.

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. It virtually definitely could be done in a single activity.
2. SQLite can store integer, floats and doubles. You may wish to read [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)